# Excercise to strengthen for writing speed

Tags: exercise, fingers

I have a exam which involves lots of writing 50 pages 3 hr , nine times in 6 days. I can increase my speed by simply writing practice, but is there any Gym exercise so that my writing muscles will be stronger and enduring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise - you want better stamina? I would use powerball, or some other exercises that requires squeezing. Instead of short term - high intensity, use lower intensity, and train longer. Please observe your body, elbows a specially. You can develop golf elbow, and that is quite tricky to get rid of. You need to stop, and rest... and you have exam.

### EDIT

And agree that it can be done anywhere, not only at the gym. For instance you can buy something to squeeze, like de-stress ball, and squeeze it while watching TV...

Other from that. Famous violin players ware able to squeeze porcelain cups. So strong their fingers ware. Also talk with guitar players - they have strong fingers too. Problem is that writing requires more precision, and your pain comes from having muscles stretched to control pen.